# How to debug when using Google VR (Daydream) and Unity?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, daydream

I'm using the latest Google VR SDK and Unity 5.6. I've got a Daydream headset/controller and I'm trying to develop a game. I've been stuck on a problem for a while now, which in a typical Unity environment I should be able to solve very quickly, but because I'm forced to build/run the code to the device each time I want to test I'm unable to view the console nor see any error/warnings which are thrown.

Any idea on how I can debug using Unity, or even emulate the Daydream controller/headset within Unity? I've seen that a controller emulator exists, but it appears you still have to run on the device, only in that scenario you have to have two phones; one acting as the controller and another as the 'screen'.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this asset [Log Viewer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12047).

Using this asset you can see the same log console in Unity Editor in runtime. I don't know about DayDream but it worked for me on Android, Oculus, and GearVR.

Comment: I personally enjoyed using the asset a lot & recommended to a few of developers I know of. If it worked for you please mark your question as solved. Thanks :)